# AWS sam local start api with lambda written in java and packaged as docker image

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I have implemented the lambda function using java (taken from the docs actually).

```
package trial;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.util.Map;

public class Handler implements RequestHandler<Map<String,Object>, String>{
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Map<String,Object> event, Context context)
    {
        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
        String response = "200 OK";
        // log execution details
        logger.log("ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES: " + gson.toJson(System.getenv()));
        logger.log("CONTEXT: " + gson.toJson(context));
        // process event
        logger.log("EVENT: " + gson.toJson(event));
        logger.log("EVENT TYPE: " + event.getClass().toString());
        return response;
    }
}
```

Then I packed it in a docker image:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/java:11

COPY lib/* ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/lib/

CMD [ "trial.Handler::handleRequest" ]
```

Then, using AWS CDK I want to use this image as lambda handler:

```
  const repo = aws.aws_ecr.Repository.fromRepositoryArn(
    construct, "repoId", "arn:aws:ecr:eu-west-1:***ACCOUNTID***:repository/repo"
  )

  const lambda1 = new aws.aws_lambda.DockerImageFunction(construct, "HelloFunction", {
    code: aws.aws_lambda.DockerImageCode.fromEcr(repo),
  })

  const api = new aws.aws_apigateway.LambdaRestApi(construct, 'sample-api', {
    handler: lambda1
  })
```

I can deploy this lambda to AWS and everything works as expected.

But it doesn't work when I want to test it using AWS SAM local.

```
sam local start-api -t cdk.out/HelloCdkStack.template.json --warm-containers EAGER
```

I get an error:

```
    "resourceId": "123456",
    "resourcePath": "/{proxy+}",
    "stage": "prod"
  },
  "resource": "/{proxy+}",
  "version": "1.0"
}EVENT TYPE: class java.util.LinkedHashMapEND RequestId: 9a7201d8-7b4b-486e-9208-2da9a8972347
REPORT RequestId: 9a7201d8-7b4b-486e-9208-2da9a8972347  Duration: 9.99 ms       Billed Duration: 10 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB     Max Memory Used: 128 MB 
Invalid lambda response received: Lambda returned <class 'str'> instead of dict
2022-12-23 01:30:24 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2022 01:30:24] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 -
```

** UPDATE, solved

The Handler must return Object for unknown reason.

```
    return Map.of(
        "statusCode", 200,
        "body", "test response",
        "headers", Map.of(
        "Content-Type", "application/json"
        )
    );
```

Comment: Which version of the CLI and SAM are you using? At a glance, try doing `let response={statusCode:200,headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},body:"200 OK"};` instead of `String response = "200 OK";` and see if that works?

Comment: CDK CLI: 2.56.0, SAM CLI: 1.67.0.

Comment: Looks like I used java 8 for compilation lambda, now I switched to 17, a previous error has gone but I got new one: `Invalid lambda response received: Lambda response must be valid json`

Comment: Did you change the value of `response` as above?

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried to return `Map.of("statusCode", 200,"body", "test response","headers", Map.of("Content-Type", "application/json")) but the error stays the same

Comment: It works now, you were right, the Handler must return Object, not a String.